# Must an AirBNB place be disinfected or sanitized prior to checkin?

Tags: utah

I recently stayed at an AirBNB in Utah County, and have reason to believe the cleaning staff did not apply disinfectant where necessary prior to my entering the property. Is this a health code violation?

Comment: Off-topic, but: Whether it is a good idea to use disinfectant as a general precaution is very much in dispute - there are indications it does more harm than good. I believe the consensus is that unless specific infectious diseases are involved, conventional cleaning is sufficient (and preferred).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, UT Administrative Code R392-502 may be my friend here:

Hotel, Motel or Resort - shall include tourist court, motor hotel, resort 
    camps, hostels, lodges, dormitories and similar facilities, and shall mean
    every building, or structure with all buildings and facilities in connection, 
    kept, used, maintained as, advertised as, or held out to the public to be, **a 
    place where living accommodations are furnished to transient guests or to

    groups normally occupying such facilities on a seasonal or short-term basis.**

6.6 All eating and drinking utensils for use by guests in rooms, shall be either single service, or washed and sanitized in a manner prescribed in R392-100 and protected from subsequent contamination.

6.11 All buildings, rooms and equipment and ground surrounding them shall be maintained in a clean and operable condition.

Comment: So, unless there is some other relevant law, or the phrase "where necessary" in your question referred only to eating and drinking utensils, the answer to your question appears to be "no".

Comment: @NateEldredge it's also worth noting that most disinfectants are unsuitable for eating utensils and the like; these should be sanitized by washing and drying at high temperatures.

Comment: @Nate: I'll have to do a bit more digging.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Actually, upon rereading my answer - since an Airbnb accommodation possibly counts as "a place where living accommodations are furnished to transient guests or to
groups normally occupying such facilities on a seasonal or short-term basis" - it would be subject to 6.6 and 6.11 as posted. Thus, depending on how "clean" is defined, the accommodation in question could have committed a health code violation.